# SMS intercepted and edited before arriving?

Tags: samsung

I'm hoping someone here can help me with something. 
The other day I received a text message from someone and the latter half of it was odd and didn't have anything to do with the conversation.

When I asked the person who sent it they said they never sent it... even though it was part of the original message bubble that i received from them. I even looked at their phone and the part in question was not there on their phone.

So i'm wondering: is it possible for someone to edit out/delete part of their sent sms? Or is there software out there where someone could possibly intercept a message, ad to it, and then pass it along so only the receiver has the "additional" parts?

I'm using a samsung galaxy ace 2 an they have a samsung 3. Sorry if this is vague or not specific enough technically... just confused and don't know much about this stuff.

Comment: I would like to know as well and I'm hoping this has already been discussed somewhere.

Comment: i saw some really technical responses regarding some form of intercept but it was a lot of talk about scripts and whatnot which i don't really understand. more just wanting to know if what i mentioned was a possibility.

Comment: afaik you can't edit/delete a text after you've already sent it. if that's true then the text in question was edited before i got it an after it was sent to me.

Answer (score 0):

Technically in Android you can alter SMS stored, so you can modify, them after received, and before presented to the user. Of course a malicious application can hide a received SMS and delete it before the user knows it.

About a SMS modification before sent, no you can not, but you can modify the stored copy in your phone just after it has been sent. With rooted phones it could be possible if the intercepter app has root permissions.

In Android KitKat and up only the main SMS application can perform this kind of tasks.

Comment: `it could be possible if the intercepter app has root permissions.` -- Do you know any such interceptor app or ever read about it somewhere? Please mention its name or the source as I would like to test it.

Comment: Check this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550178/intercepting-outgoing-sms